# How to close client sessions after all tests are completed with pytest?

Tags: python, linux, session, pytest, fixtures

I have some tests  which all use some clients I create with fixtures using `pytest`, for example a S3 boto3 client:

```
@pytest.fixture
async def s3_client():
    aws_key_id = os.getenv("AWS_KEY_ID")
    aws_access_key = os.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY")
    s3_client = await aioboto3.client(
        "s3", aws_access_key_id=aws_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=aws_access_key
    ).__aenter__()

    return s3_client
```

what is the suggested way to close this session when all my tests have been completed?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found this solution. `Pytest` allows you to run tear-down code for each fixture inside the fixture methods. For this to happen, the `return` statement is replaced with a `yield` statement. `Pytest` makes the fixture **up to the yield statement** and then at the end of the test it goes back to the fixture and runs the tear-down code after the `yield` statement.

So for the case of the question:

```
@pytest.fixture
async def s3_client():
    aws_key_id = os.getenv("AWS_KEY_ID")
    aws_access_key = os.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY")
    s3_client = await boto3.client(
        "s3", aws_access_key_id=aws_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=aws_access_key
    ).__aenter__()

    yield s3_client
    
    await s3_client.__aexit__(None, None, None)
```

For more details [read the docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#yield-fixtures-recommended).